# A word that means "destroy something beyond repair"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a verb which can convey the meaning of damaging or breaking something beyond repair. Here is a sample sentence:

"I didn't expect that of you! You just _____ my heart!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of all the synonyms given at Thesaurus.com for [obliterate{d}](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/obliterate) and [destroye{d}](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/destroy), I'd say that only **shattered** fits at all well here.

There are 341 000 Google hits for "shattered my heart", which is more forceful than the more common "broke my heart".

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shatter) gives the 'beyond repair' sense:

> **shatter**  transitive verb
>
> ...
>
> 2 a : to break at once into pieces
>
> b : to damage badly : ruin
>
> 3 : to cause the disruption or annihilation of : demolish

and [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shatter) adds:

> **shatter** verb ...
>
> 1.1 [with object] Damage or destroy (something abstract)
>
> ‘the crisis will shatter their confidence’
>
> 2 [with object] Upset (someone) greatly.
>
> ‘everyone was shattered by the news’

The latter usage is obviously closely related to the example given in the question.

Comment: "Obliterate" also means "destroyed beyond repair", but I think it can only be applied to sites (things at a specific location).

Answer (score 0):

Decimate.

Happily it has two accepted meanings according to [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/decimate)

> 1. to destroy or kill a large proportion of: a plague decimated the population.
> 2. (Military) (esp in the ancient Roman army) to kill every tenth man of (a mutinous section)

While I think the first definition is exaggeration in your context, I could agree with the second (interpreted as "reduce by 10%), and I like the ambiguity here.